# Possibly rotated parabola from three points

Tags: algebra-precalculus, conic-sections

I'm looking for a possibly rotated parabola in the plane, i.e., the solution to a quadric like
$$
Ax^2 + 2Bxy + Cy^2 + Dx + Ey + F = 0
$$
where exactly one of the eigenvalues of 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
A & B \\ B & C
\end{bmatrix}
$$
is zero, and where the solution set is nonempty.

I know the $xy$ coordinates of the *vertex* $V$ of the parabola (i.e., the point that lies on the axis of reflectional symmetry) and of two points $P$ and $Q$ of the parabola, one on each side of the vertex, so that going from $P$ to $V$ to $Q$ along the parabola involves no backtracking.

(The corresponding problem where $P$ and $Q$ might both be on the same side has multiple solutions for some configurations, but that's why I've included the "between-ness condition".)

I'd like to know either the coefficients $A, \ldots, F$, or the focus and directrix, or any other unambiguous description of the parabola that I can convert to one of these.

I keep feeling as if something from projective geometry involving perspectivities and projectivities and (2,2)-correspondences ought to make this simple, but I can't see it.

Comment: I don't see it yet, but Dorrie has several geometric/projective problems, including Newton's method for a parabola given four points and an alternative based n Desargues involution  http://store.doverpublications.com/0486613488.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure there is no simple solution for this problem.

You can assume the origin is at the vertex via the transformation
$x\mapsto x-v_1$, $y\mapsto y-v_2$.

Via a rotation you can assume that the equation is $\bar x^2=a \bar y$. 
The rotation is given by an angle $\alpha$, or equivalently, by $s=sin(\alpha)$ and
$c=cos(\alpha)$, with $c^2+s^2=1$.

Then 
$$
\bar x=c x+ s y,\quad \bar y = -s x+c y,\quad
\text{(and so $x=c\bar x-s\bar y,\quad y=s\bar x +c\bar y$)}
$$
which gives the equation of the parabola in the original variables as
$$
(cx+sy)^2=a(-sx+cy).
$$
Evaluating this equation at $P=(p_1,p_2)$ gives 
$$
a=\frac{(c p_1+s p_2 )^2}{c p_2-s p_1}.
$$
If you insert this in the equality 
$$
(cq_1+sq_2)^2=a(-sq_1+cq_2),\qquad\text{(parabola equation at $Q=(q_1,q_2)$)}
$$
and multiply by $(-sp_1+cp_2)$, you obtain the third degree equation
$$
Ac^3+Bc^2s+Cc s^2+Ds^3=0,
$$
with
$$
A=p_2 q_1^2-p_1^2 q_2,\quad B=(p_1-q_1)(p_1 q_1-2 p_2 q_2),
$$
$$
C=(p_2-q_2)(2 p_1 q_1- p_2 q_2),\quad\text{and}\quad D=p_2^2 q_1-p_1 q_2^2.
$$
It is easy to see that $AD\ne 0$ if $P\ne V$, $Q\ne V$ and the three points are not aligned, hence 
we have a third degree equation either for $\frac cs$ or $\frac sc$ (maybe for both).

Assume you solve this equation for $\frac cs$ and obtain $\frac cs=K$. Then
$$
s=\frac{1}{\sqrt{K^2+1}}\quad\text{and}\quad c=\frac{K}{\sqrt{K^2+1}},
$$
which gives you the complete solution (i.e., the equation) of the parabola, since you have $a$ in terms of $c$ and $s$.

This is NOT a construction you can carry out with ruler and compass in general,
since the values have minimal polynomials up to degree six.

For example, if $P=(1,2)$, $Q=(1,3)$, then $a\sim 0.0132968$ is a zero of the polynomial
$$
P_a(x)=50 x^6-35 x^4+11 x^2-1,
$$
$s=sin(\alpha)\sim -0.377016\ $ is a zero of the polynomial
$$
P_s(x)=50 x^6-165 x^4+5656 x^2-1,
$$
and  $c=cos(\alpha)\sim 0.926207\ $ is a zero of the polynomial
$$
P_c(x)=50 x^6-115 x^4+91 x^2-25.
$$

So, in general you have to solve a third degree equation, which I think is not simple. You can always choose $a$ to be greater than zero, and
you must choose solutions of $c,s$ such that $\bar P_x \bar Q_x=(cp_1+sp_2)(cq_1+sq_2)<0$, in order that $V$ is between $P$ and $Q$.

Maybe one can use the Origami constructive geometry to do this in a simpler way.

Comment: Thanks. This answer's a little frustrating, for the presence of the cubic suggests that when $P$ and $Q$ are on the *same* side of the vertex, then if there are two solutions, there should be *three* solutions, but I can't seem to convince myself of that. Anyhow, this is pretty much what I needed. I wasn't hoping for ruler-and-compass -- this is actually a practical problem for some software a friend's working on.

Comment: In the case when P and Q are on the same side of the vertex, you have the same equations as above: only the choice of a specific solution gives you V between P and Q. For example $V=(0,0)$, $P=(1,1)$, $Q=(2,4)$ yields two solutions with P and Q on the same side of V, but one solution with V between P and Q. If the three points are not aligned, there will be always one solution with V between P and Q.

Comment: Ah...excellent. That makes some sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

John, I got qualitatively the same result, by what I think is a somewhat different method. I started with $P=(a,b,1)$, $V=(0,0,1)$, $Q=(c,d,1)$ and an arbitrary point $I=(t,1,0)$ on the line at infinity, and drew the conic passing through these four, but tangent to the line at infinity at $I$.

For a rotation about $V$, the indeterminate $t$ is the tangent of the angle necessary to rotate through to bring $I$ to $I'=(0,1,0)$; the corresponding sine and cosine are $t\big/\sqrt{1+t^2}$ and $1\big/\sqrt{1+t^2}$, respectively. The transformed points $P'$ and $Q'$ I’ll not write down here, but the conic passing through $P'$, $V$, $Q'$, and $I'$ will have equation $y=Ax^2+Bx$, no constant ’cause it passes through the origin. And $V$ is the vertex of this parabola if and only if $B=0$.

Plugging the coordinates of $P'$ and $Q'$ into this, you get
$$
B=\frac{\frac{(a-bt)^2}{1+t^2}\frac{ct+d}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}
-\frac{(c-dt)^2}{1+t^2}\frac{at+b}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}}\Delta\,,
$$
of which we only want a condition for zeroness. So the equation for $t$ seems to be the cubic $(a-bt)^2(ct+d)-(c-dt)^2(at+b)=0$.
I tried $P=(-1,1)$, $Q=(5,2)$, and got the equation $-23 + 54t - 12t^2 + 9t^3=0 $, assuming I typed everything in correctly; and of course my hand computations above would need to be checked as well. But I think the principle is valid. For my example, the derivative has negative discriminant, so the polynomial is increasing. At least in this case there is only the one real root.

Comment: Ah...that has more of the feel I was expecting -- something about writing things involving conics in projective space just seems right -- but the answer seems to be pretty much the same, in the sense that one ends up solving a cubic I'll sit down and work through what you did myself, and if both our "by-hand" efforts agree, I'll be convinced. Thanks!

Comment: I just multiplied the whole mess out, and got $(b^2c-ad^2)t^3 + (b^2d-bd^2-2abc+2acd)t^2+(a^2c-ac^2-2abd+2bcd)t +a^2d-bc^2$, a pleasingly symmetric result.